# Hyperledger Explorer Test Fail

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

After configuring as show in the Readme fit in Hyperledger explore and making md5 to trust I have managed to come this far. I am currently using an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server.

```
Test explorerpg.sql for DDL statements syntax verification
        ✓ should read the file explorerpg.sql for ddl statements 
    TAP version 13
    # Test Results
    ok 1 DROP USER IF EXISTS testuser;
    not ok 2 WITH PASSWORD 'password';
      ---
        operator: fail
        at: <anonymous> (/home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/postgrespgtest.js:2:5157)
        stack: |-
          Error: WITH PASSWORD 'password';
              at Test.assert [as _assert] (/home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:228:54)
              at Test.bound [as _assert] (/home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:80:32)
              at Test.fail (/home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:322:10)
              at Test.bound [as fail] (/home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/node_modules/tape/lib/test.js:80:32)
              at /home/hrm/hrm-explorer/app/test/postgrespgtest.js:2:5157
              at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
      ...
```

Test fails of: # tests 65, # pass  43, # fail  22

Moreover `npm ERR! Failed at the hyperledger-explorer-test@0.3.9 test script`

Answer (score 1):

The error has been fixed in [the recent Pull Request](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/pull/128). You won't see it any more in the latest codebase (v1.1.0).